# SSRS Report to filter down to specific parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS Geographic Report that selects project records which can have more than 1 geographic area selected per record.  I have parameters to request the region, electoral area and city.  These are working fine, just when selecting only 1 city all records show that have that city selected even if they have other cities selected.

I need a SQL Query to say, if project has @city selected then show only projects that have ONLY @city selected...

For example, my report below, I have selected the region, and electoral area of Cranbrook, then in the city parameter, the available listing is Cranbrook and Rockyview (Great!).

In Figure 1, I have selected both Cranbrook and Rockyview.  This shows 3 projects , 2 projects have both cranbrook and rockyview tagged, and 1 project only has Cranbrook selected. Perfect!

Figure 1

[image: Figure 1]

Now, in figure 2, I have selected the region, and electoral area of Cranbrook, then I chose only Cranbrook city.  All 3 projects still come up, but I  distinctly want only those projects tagged  just with Cranbrook.

So in figure 2, I should see only project #3426 come up in my listing. But they all display..

Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

My dataset query:

```
SELECT Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralareaidname
  , Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_name AS City
  , Filteredcbt_project.cbt_imsnumber 
  , Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralidname
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_committedamount
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_commitmentavailable
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_commitmentdisbursed
  , Filteredcbt_project.cbt_organizationlegalnameidname
  , Filteredcbt_project.statuscodename
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_projectnameid
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_programfiscalyearidname
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname
  , Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict.cbt_name AS [Regional District]
FROM Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_electoralarea ON Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict.cbt_regionaldistrictid = Filteredcbt_electoralarea.cbt_regionaldistrictid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_category
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_program ON Filteredcbt_category.cbt_categoryid = Filteredcbt_program.cbt_categoryid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_project ON Filteredcbt_program.cbt_programid = Filteredcbt_project.cbt_programnameid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear ON Filteredcbt_project.cbt_projectid = Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_projectnameid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea ON Filteredcbt_project.cbt_projectid = Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_projectid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_geographicarea ON Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid = Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid 
        ON Filteredcbt_electoralarea.cbt_electoralareaid = Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralareaid
WHERE        (Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralareaidname IN (@Area)) AND    (Filteredcbt_project.statuscodename IN (@Status)) AND 
                     (Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname IN (@FiscalYear)) AND (Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict.cbt_name IN (@Regional)) AND 
                     (Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_name IN (@City)) 

ORDER BY Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname
ORDER BY Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname;
```

So, the table structure is connected like this:

**Filteredcbt_project** holds all the project related information, PK is cbt_projectid

**Filteredcbt_geographicarea** holds all the geographic area id's and city informaiton

**Filteredcbt_cbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea** is the intersect table between projects and geographic areas.  This holds the cities that are tagged to each project ID.

Filteredcbt_project is linked to Filteredcbt_cbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea by the **cbt_projectid**.

The Filteredcbt_geographicarea table is linked to Filteredcbt_cbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea by **cbt_geographicareaid**

**SAMPLES:**

Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea sample: This example shows that one project ID can have multiple geographic areas tagged

```
    cbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicareaid  cbt_geographicareaid     cbt_projectid

    A6D7292F-EA05-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9  4EB4F611-4BD1     2C2FC521-EA05-E411  

    998F9FE5-2806-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9  38B4F611-4BD1      54FD66DD-2806-E411 
9A8F9FE5-2806-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9     7EB4F611-4BD1       54FD66DD-2806-E411

(same project ID's on the last two)
```

Filteredcbt_geographicarea sample: These are the geographical areas.

```
cbt_electoralareaid    cbt_electoralareaidname  cbt_geographicareaid    cbt_name(city)

16B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9 Town of Creston         2EB4F611-4BD1-E311 Alice Siding

13B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9 RDCK Area I             2FB4F611-4BD1-E311 Thrums

0EB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9 RDCK Area D             30B4F611-4BD1-E311 Ainsworth
```

Filteredcbt_project example:

```
cbt_imsnumber   cbt_programnameid   cbt_projectid
3397    F38AEF17-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193    48F7E223-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193
3398    F58AEF17-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193    4AF7E223-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193
3426    D18AEF17-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193    44F7E223-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193
```

I hope this helps, I really need to get some answers... I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Can you please show us the query that gets the data. If you can put some sample data up too, that will help us if we need to test our fix. Nothing that is sensitive, just something we can look at to see where the problem is.

Comment: Put your table structure and sample data here .

Comment: Thank you! I have placed the query, table structure and example data above.. I hope this helps, I really need some answers and appreciate ALL the time to assist!

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?  I am wondering if I can maybe use lookupset to try to match parameters exactly, but I see the problem is that the city is tagged on other projects and will come up no matter what.  However, maybe there could be some code that will say if a city selected in the parameter do not show the projects that have multiple cities selected... I am not sure how to do this, and I cannot figure this out.  I have gotten no responses on any forum..